# Cognos Reports are not distributed to al the mail id's

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

I am facing this issue in cognos 8.4 , my reports are not sent to all the receipient mail id's , but only some are getting the reports , i don't see any error in the history , i can see the message as report delivered to all the mail id's , i have checked the error log but no error either there, i have pinged the mail server from cognos , there is no issue with it , can anyone help me regarding this issue

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There's no programming question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending to Groups (Distribution Lists), please check if groups are allowed in AD to receive system generated emails. This happened to us as well back in 2011 :)